# Is there a way to make IntelliJ autocomplete custom-named property files?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-properties

I have a custom-named property file inside a library, e.g. `foo.properties` which I then load in a configuration class, like so:

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"/foo.properties"})
public class FooConfiguration {}
```

IntelliJ doesn't recognise `foo.properties` as a Spring properties file and doesn't autocomplete it. Is there a way to hint to IntelliJ to treat this as a Spring properties file?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe <resource> 
       <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory> 
   </resource> in pom.xml can helps you

Comment: The folder is marked as a resource already :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that possible.

But you can install some alternative plugins for your intelliJ like [tabnine](https://www.tabnine.com/).

Comment: property files are well defined in Spring, I just need to make a file behave like one :)